# Typescript Conditional Statement doesn't filter values?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js, typescript4.0

When I use Typescript Conditional Statement it doesn't remove the values. For example, if the type of "`ErrorsType`" is `string` | `null`, and I use `ErrorsType extends string ? InHereTheValueOf'ErrorsType'IsStill'String'|'null'InsteadOf'String' : InHereTheValueOf'ErrorsType'IsStill'String'|'null'InsteadOf'null'`

Here is my code:

```js
export const BotErrors = {
    test: (reason: string) => `This error bc of ${reason}`,
    ValueTooLow: 'You can not reduce value below 0',
};

type ErrorsType = typeof BotErrors;

export default class SomeError<T extends keyof ErrorsType> extends Error {
    constructor(code: T, ...args: ErrorsType[T] extends Function ? Parameters<ErrorsType[T]> : []) {
        let msg: string | Function = BotErrors[code];
        if (typeof msg === 'function') msg = msg(...args) as string;
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

At `ErrorsType[T]` got error: `Type 'Function & { test: (reason: string) => string; ValueTooLow: string; }[T]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.` Because of the `BotErrors` have both function and string as it's value.

After I add `// @ts-nocheck` everything is fine, even with type definition. But I'm try wondering if there is any way to not ignore errors?

Comment: What's "`HavenErrors`"? Could you make sure your code is a [mre] where the only problem is the one you're asking about?  The specific issue you're running into seems to be that the `Function` interface is an untyped function call and is *not* considered a subtype of `(...args: any) => any` (as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/m337Lm)), which is what `Parameters<>` wants.  If you fix that [then your particular error goes away](https://tsplay.dev/wXzD8m) but then there are other errors, which are out of scope for the question as asked.

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I forgot to modify that part of the code, lemme do that now, the Haven is the name of the bot and I forgot to change it to `BotErrors`

Comment: @jcalz Lemme look into the links you send and I'll leave a respond :D

Comment: I got no more questions, the code is working now. You can write an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll try to write up an answer today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
ErrorsType[T] extends Function ? Parameters<ErrorsType[T]> : []
```

is that [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is [defined as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/00eb22030f92a0acf15ec7af3a0881c829aa54b0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1624)

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = 
   T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

where its type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) `(...args: any) => any`,

while you have only checked the `ErrorsType[T]` type argument against [the `Function` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function).  And while `(...args: any) => any` is assignable to `Function`, the reverse is not true: just because something is a `Function` the compiler does not know that it is a `(...args: any) => any`.  The `Function` type is best avoided in general, since it represents *untyped* function calls.

Anyway it's easy enough to fix this; just change the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) check from `Function` to `(...args: any) => any`:

```
ErrorsType[T] extends (...args: any) => any ? Parameters<ErrorsType[T]> : []
```

Or the equivalent inlined version:

```
ErrorsType[T] extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : []
```

This makes the error you mentioned go away.  Note that once this is resolved your example code has other errors, but those are out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wEIRgUSlaVOAXjgG8AoOOGYdALjgAopgBDVFR9KAS2QDmAShIA+OAAMAKgAteRYPmhwARgjgQAZnAAkZVhxQBfCQBoqcAGpsANgFdgUiBAAyEAO6MA5AE0IdxDZkOGRsOFYAEzsEYDgAN1sHVWAbDzgABi9zIwBuCgoYAE8wWLwCKFQpYtjSIpKtOCxcJQq8ilBIWDgI4E02Oxt4BBsOIgBlCABbYDLoAB4pOFBaZAiiAGtgQobZiqqS8WXgVaJd8gsAegu4XcrqgG0pAF0lkBW15gA6b7YoAVRGEFCiJiOIgXAAPxwAAKvzY01oFTmt32wEeT3EjHuTwsSDQMCg0Rg0CYSB6jCkpjg30+v3+jBRD2er3eRCYNLpALg-E0ihhILByEKkJhcCxTxElGo1AuACpqd84LKLhZqKg7CUoEwhHlqEYKPr8sh4XQwGwYnBZPIAJKoAASHmtAHV-DYIgARCCyYBOmQQGyOOSCc7UPHoVTYW4kEPS2gMZgGTjIbgE-jCMSSK0KFqqdQNPSJ4xmVVWRKOZxuTxwXz+QLBULwSLRWIJeyxFQpNKZczSjQwGSKK2CRgsdhJlN8QRU-grVC8IqMZB2SYdqACzNybPlXMabQFsfGODuecyOBsOCQdx8hoQOJ8vQz45zopGACE74kFly+WodVKLTuEpoz-BoVEjADdRoaobhaABBP4iFIMg4HuABpblgk2bZtEZEongZADUTQl4jhOL4fgQxgeT5WD13BKFYLFFCXn1UMUHDAB9MDmnKLlkLQjC4CwnY4IQ-C4B4NM4AAH2YdkKPpGDyng-5iPXSTBBEIxo24242lDEZUHGKYZhaOZ0NIj5hJwwjqkON5jg+M4pWlMMCSJEkyWARhUKpDlKKU6AVNQNSY17AN4EmVABGjLjwN4+4vKeSDe14bQmBA7Qopi4hcurTQ7GQBAYF4FAvBEbLo2y+TaQQkQOAk1NBBS6V1U1Jhsp1EtWLgQ02PxJZo2QYB3DgCZpl2JgACJsAHKAhwEKaqSm1AwF4BBhU0Zw1iWuAAE50kOrr+s4ANPlSAQmGAHU4CuFCXAAeQAcXErMlhzNRdwktaNrgLaIA+Y9+zPC8PGvbRbz5A7DvfV84ANIA)